# Whitespace after n character and after every n-1 character following

Tags: java, regex

I trying to create a regex for adding one whitespace after the `n` first character of a string and another one after every `n-1` character following like this :

`AZEOHNUEAOONA` => `AZEO HNU EAO ONA`

`MAIH31354ZEHIA212AE` => `MAIH 313 54Z EHI A21 2AE`

Please can someone help me out? I have tried searching online for a similar problem, however it's very difficult to phrase it correctly in a search.

Edit : i using java 8

Comment: please add the language you are using when posting these kind of questions!

Comment: i just have edit my post

Comment: Is there something in particular you tried?

Comment: i have already try something like this : `reference.replaceAll("{4}", "$0 ");` but i don't know how to say after the first one take every n-1 result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :)

```
class Sample {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(addSpaces("AZEOHNUEAOONA",4));
    }
    public static String addSpaces(String str,int n)
    {
        String reg = "(?<=.{" + n + "})(?=(.{"+ (n-1) + "})+$)";
        String rep = "$0 ";
        return str.replaceAll(reg,rep);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AZEO HNU EAO ONA
```

Comment: I think that the `O`'s is just a happy coincidence

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use regular expressions only for one part of the problem. So basically, you split your string by taking the first `n` characters and then using the regular expressions on the remaining characters.

So basically, something like so:

```
    int n = 4;
    String str = "FOOOFOOFOOFOOFOO";
    String part1 = str.substring(0, n);
    String part2 = str.substring(n, str.length());
    System.out.println(part1 + " " + part2.replaceAll("(.{3})", "$1 ").trim());
```

Yields:

```
FOOO FOO FOO FOO FOO
```